# vimで行末でない空白文字を表示する方法

Tags: vim

最近vimを使い始めました。
行中の半角空白を表示したいのですが、検索しても行末の空白を表示する方法しか見当たりません。
行末ではない空白を表示する方法は無いのでしょうか。

検索などで表示させるのではなく、`listchars`で指定したときのように、違う文字・記号を割り当てる方法はないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v7.4.710`のパッチが当たっている環境であれば、`listchars`に`space`を指定してやれば任意の文字や記号に置き換えができるようです(以下は`_`に置き換える例)。

```
set listchars+=space:_
```

[本家SOの関連質問・回答(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374234/2322778)

---

上記のパッチが当たっていない環境でも、以下のような設定でハイライトさせる方法もありました。

```
highlight WhiteSpace cterm=underline ctermfg=lightgreen ctermbg=4
match WhiteSpace / \+/
```

`ctermfg`,`ctermbg`はコンソールで利用する場合の設定なので、GUI(gvim)を利用する場合は`guifg`,`guibg`に置き換えてください。

[本家SOの関連質問・回答(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40498439/2322778)

Answer (score 7):

簡単にやるならば

```
:match Error / /
```

とやるのが良いかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

"行末ではない空白を表示する"のは否定先読みでも可能です。

> / \%($)\@!

(\の前は半角スペースがはいってます。)
行末のスペースにはヒットしません。

Comment: qiitaのリンクも残しておきます。https://qiita.com/kawaz/items/d0708a4ab08e572f38f3